# MYSQL 5.6 Command line client for Windows Automatically closing

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

I need to create and manage connections to database servers using mysql Workbench and Mysql server. I have installed mysql-installer-community-5.6.35.0. But when I open MYSQL command line client, it automatically closes. I have already checked the status in services, it shows *running*. Any Suggestions as to how can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Which file does your shortcut target?

Comment: "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysql.exe" "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" "-uroot" "-p" "--default-character-set=utf8"

Answer (score 0):

It's a known, but weirdly, seemingly unresolved issue when it comes to MySQL. However, it's a bug with your Windows users' privileges most likely. The workaround is to open the Command prompt (cmd), `cd` into the MySQL installation folder and execute *mysql.exe* from there.